# I am adding my own css it is working only once after that it is not working

Tags: magento2, css

I have added a css through this way

> app/design/frontend/theme/magento_theme/layout
>   "default_head_block.xml"

In this `<css src="css/own.css"/>` i run the command **setup:static-content:deploy** after that the **css** is working after that i have added more **css** into the file but it is not working.

I have deleted the **generated** folder by run `rm -rf *`
deleted the `pub/static/frontend` but at the end my new **css** is not working.

And i am not understanding why is that so .

Comment: inspect element browser on your page, open your edited css file in separated tab and try to refresh to check is your css file already updated or not

Comment: i have inspected it but nothing changed .

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your css file in "default_head_block.xml".

you can put your css in app\design\frontend\theme\themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
<head>      
    <css src="Magento_Theme::css/file.css"/>
</head>
```